# Checking Type Inside Collection in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I am kind of new to C# and not sure about the following:
I have a parameter defined as follows:

```
public Collection<object> InputObject
        {
            get { return inputObject; }
            set { inputObject= value; }
        }
        private Collection<object> inputObject;
```

As you can see, the object is a collection of objects since I am expecting different types.

When later I want to check the type, what is the right way?
I tried this:

```
if (inputObject is Collection<MyDefinedObject>)
{

}
```

but I get an underlined warning that the given expression is never of the expected type. What is the right way to check for a type within a collection?

Thanks

Comment: at a given time are all the objects inside the collection are of same type?

Comment: are you checking one of the objects? all of them?

Comment: @ParvSharma : the answer is YES to your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You have a collection of Object**

When you write

```
Collection<object>
```

that means you are defining a collection that can contain *any* object.

When you do that, you can then do something like

```
inputObject.Add(new MyDefinedObject());
inputObject.Add(new StringBuilder()));
```

and you end up with different types in your collection.

**Checking specific elements of your collection**

If you want to test the type of a *specific* object in that collection you could so something like

```
Type t = inputObject[0].GetType();
```

or

```
if (inputObject[0] is MyDefinedObject)
```

The code

```
if (inputObject is Collection<MyDefinedObject>)
```

will never be true because you already defined

```
private Collection<object> inputObject;
```

meaning you defined the type of the *collection* inputObject to be `Collection<object>`

**What if I want everything in the collection to be MyDefinedObject?**

*Based on your comments below your question, this is what you really want...*

```
private Collection<MyDefinedObject> inputObject;
```

**The Error Message You are Getting**

> but I get an underlined warning that the given expression is never of the expected type

That is because inputObject is of type `Collection<object>`, which is *never* of type *Collection*.  That's like saying an apple is never a banana.

**A Better Approach**

If you are using generics and receiving a generic collection, why not create a generic function to process that collection too?

```
private void ProcessCollection<T>(Collection<T> inputObject)
{
}

// Somewhere else in your code...

Collection<MyDefinedObject> inputObject = // Initialize this however you do now
ProcessCollection<MyDefinedObject>(inputObject);
```

Comment: At any instance of time, my collection will have exactly ONE object type Collection<MyDefinedObject> or Collection<MyOtherObject> ...etc

Comment: @Saher Just because a `Collection<object>` happens to contain only elements of type `string` doesn't actually mean it's a `Collection<string>`.  it's still just a `Collection<object>`.  The point is that you *could* add an int, or a double, or whatever, if you wanted to.  You would need to make a new collection if you wanted to turn it into a `Collection<string>`.

Comment: @Saher If you happen to know that you won't ever be adding objects of a different type then you should change the program so that you never create a `Collection<object>` but rather a `Collection` of that specific type in the first place.

Comment: It will be different types but the program is generic and expect different collections every time. Once is it Collection<Object1> another time it is Collection<Object2> ...etc

Comment: anyway I will check the size and then InputObject[0] to avoid the exception

Comment: Look at the last update to my question.  I think you will find that approach better.

Answer (score 2):

Since your `Collection<>` contains `object`, the collection has (in essence) no type. You either give the collection an actual type, or you check the items IN the collection for a type.

Comment: A collection of objects does indeed have a type.  The type is `Collection<object>`

Answer (score 1):

All object inherits the base class object, then you can use :

```
if(InputObject[0].GetType()==typeof(string)){
//string is an example and 0 can be replaced with a index
}
```

to know which type is each object

Comment: or just use (is) keyword                                                          
if(InputObject[0] is string)

Comment: this is prone to Exception (Out of range) What if the list was empty?

Comment: This was intented as an example... would be normally used in a for loop :P

Comment: Oh I see. I actually know that the Collection will have the same type of object at some instance of time.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need to check all.  The collection is defined as object

```
foreach (object obj in InputObject)
{
    obj.gettype();     
    if (obj is DocFieldEnumHierTwoSpeedLoader) x= 5;
}
```

Comment: at any given time, the collection will have one type of object

Comment: OK, but the collection does not know that.  If you are sure then just check InputObject[0].

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you want:

```
        var defined = InputObject.OfType<MyDefinedObject>();
        var other = InputObject.OfType<MyOtherDefinedObject>();

        bool hasDefined = defined.Any();
        bool hasOther = other.Any();
```

Answer (score 0):

You say that the inputObject property can contain collections whose collection type can vary from time to time.  There are two solutions:

1) If the type of the collection's elements is always the same for a given instance of the type that defines the property, make that type generic:

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
    public Collection<T> InputObject 
    { 
        get { return inputObject; } 
        set { inputObject= value; } 
    } 
    private Collection<T> inputObject; 
}
```

If the *same instance* of the property could hold collections with varying element types, then declare the field as `object`, or, perhaps better, as a non-generic interface type:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public ICollection InputObject
    {
        get { return inputObject; } 
        set { inputObject= value; }  // you should add some type checking here 
                                     //to make sure an invalid collection type isn't passed in
    }
    private ICollection inputObject;
    public Collection<T> GetTypedCollection<T>()
    {
        return (Collection<T>)inputObject; 
    }
}
```

The GetTypedCollection method requires that you know at compile time what the collection's type is; if that's not possible, you'll need to post more sample code so we can suggest a solution.